# javascript If-Else Statement skip If condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

As you can see in the picture the value of the `r.SalaryGrade` is `null`. Why it skip my `IF` condition and goes to `Else`?. I make sure that if is an empty string and null it will add a class to a textbox. Did I do something wrong?.

```
 if (r.SalaryGrade == "" && r.SalaryGrade == null) { $("#JobGradeId").addClass('validation'); }
 else { $("#JobGradeId").removeClass('validation'); }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure in Javascript `'' != null`, in other words that if statement will never be entered as you want it to be an empty string *and* null.

Comment: Maybe swap and- `&&` for or- `||` ?

Comment: `if (r.SalaryGrade == "" || r.SalaryGrade == null)`

Comment: Read it out loud. Grade equal to empty string AND Grade equal to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition has an "&&" in it.

```
'' and null are different things
```

You need to change how you structure that if statement. You could do something like,

```
r.SalaryGrade == "" || r.SalaryGrade == null
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why at first I try it before I post It didn't work. Maybe because of my browser cache. BTW Thanks. 8 Mins to accept.

Comment: No prob. Keep fighting the good fight. Browser cache is your worst enemy sometimes, and will have you hunting down problems that don't really exist. I know the struggle.

Answer (score 1):

r.salaryGrade = "" as the first conditional passed, therefore it cannot be equal to null ( as it HAS a value of "" which is not null ).

You can change the && to an || and if either is true it will continue on.

Answer (score 1):

As there is && in the if statement. it does not go in the if statement. Just try this for clarification- just make an if statement

String s= "";

IF(s == null)
print "it is null";

else
print "it is not null";

See yourself whether String s can be empty and null at the same time.